# Noob node.js installation problem: -bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Tags: node.js, installation

I'm now starting to learn node.js following an online course, but I get into trouble after I installed the latest node.js through their official website.

I'm a Mac user, as I follow the course to check if node.js is installed correctly in terminal by typing `node -v`, it shows the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vOSK.png

Even if I tried to install nvm as I google for solution, it said ==> nvm is already installed, but at the last sentence it said :

`-bash: __git_ps1: command not found`

But when I check if node is installed, it shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3QBb.png

I appreciate for your help as I can't go on learning node.js because of this.  Thanks a lot.